# The scope of JavaScript variables on auto-complete

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I have an auto-complete code like below. It gets the correct response from the ajax success, but I cannot use the response variable on grep function below it. It says that it's undefined. This case is also valid if I'm to use a global variable. How can I make it to see response variable?

```
$( ".skl" ).autocomplete({
             source: function(req, responseFn) 
             {
                var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(req.term);
                var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + re, "i");
                var matcher2 = new RegExp( " " + re, "i" );

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "http://somepage",
                    data: { skillType: 1, skillName: re},
                    success: function( response){
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                });

                var a = $.grep( availableTags, function(item,index){
                    return matcher.test((item)) || matcher2.test(item);
                });
                //var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(availableTags, req.term);
                responseFn( a.slice( 0,5) );

            },

            minLength: 1,
            autoFocus: true
        });
```

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous, so you'll have to wait for the data to return before you can use it.

Comment: I simply added a sleep function to wait for 5 seconds before grep use it. Nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ajax` is asynchronous. That means it will continue running your code immediately, before it has loaded the content (a very very good thing).

You need to move your `grep` code, and anything else that uses the result, inside your success function. A "sleep" function (such a thing doesn't exist in JavaScript so I'm skeptical) will not help you, because JavaScript will not run its queued events until the current function has finished executing. That means it's *impossible* for the ajax to have finished while still running your `autocomplete` function, even if you busywait (which is a terrible, awful thing to do anyway).

Since it seems that you need the response in order to return a value in your `source` function, you need to change the way you're thinking about things. For example, the request could be sent when the content changes, and its `success` function would *trigger* an update of the list's items. This makes more conceptual sense, too.